# Lubuntu 17.10 login screen has a white font clock

Tags: lubuntu, clock

I noticed that my Lubuntu's clock in login screen has a white font clock. I do not know why but no matter what I do it won't change. I tried resetting the panel and configuration files of LXDE, but nothing worked. I also didn't find anything that would reset the login screen, to see if it'd work.

I found out another file called `01_ubuntu.conf`, located in `/usr/share/lightdm/ligthdm-gtk-greeter.conf.d`, which shows the following:

```
[greeter]
background=/usr/share/backgrounds/warty-final-ubuntu.png
theme-name=Ambiance
icon-theme-name=LoginIcons
font-name=Ubuntu 11
xft-antialias=true
xft-dpi=96
xft-hintstyle=slight
xft-rgba=rgb
indicators=~host;~spacer;~session;~language;~a11y;~clock;~power;
clock-format=%d %b, %H:%M
```

I also have a `lightdm.conf.d` folder, but it's empty.

Is there a way to reset the login screen to default, to see if the color will go back to normal?

Comment: Is the issue the colour of the clock, or the existence of the clock?

Comment: @Kusalananda The colour. It's on a light background, so it should be dark text, but it's light text so there's not enough contrast.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. A work-around is to install the package blackbird-gtk-theme and then select the Blackbird theme instead of Lubuntu-default on the Appearance tab in 'System Tools' > 'LightDM GTK+ Greeter settings' on the LXDE application menu. With the Blackbird theme for LightDM you can see the text clearly and this theme also looks better than the default LightDM greeter theme in Lubuntu 17.10.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the color of the Clock/Hostname etc. by heading to

```
/usr/share/themes/THEME-NAME/gtk-3.20/gtk-widgets.css
```

where THEME-NAME  is Lubuntu-default normally and changeing the color

```
/*************
 * separator *
 *************/
separator {
    min-width: 1px;
    min-height: 1px;
    border-top-width: 1px;
    border-left-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-image: none;
    border-color: shade (@bg_color, 0.92);
    border-bottom-color: alpha (shade (@bg_color, 1.26), 0.6);
    border-right-color: alpha (shade (@bg_color, 1.26), 0.6);
}

treeview.view separator,
treeview separator,
separator,
separator:hover {
    color: shade (@bg_color, 0.92);    <--HERE
}
```

to anything you want, e.g.

```
    color: shade (#1e101a, 0.92);    <--HERE
```

I did the same but copied the whole Lubuntu-default directory into Lubuntu-greeter and selected Lubuntu-greeter in `lightdm-gtk-greeter-settings` to not influence the theme when being logged in.